# How to post from Windows Phone 8 to Asp.Net MVC4 WebApi and get JSON back

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httpclient, windows-phone-8

I have the following Asp.net MVC4 WebApi method def.:

```
public ApiResponse Process(string id, FormDataCollection form)...
```

that I use to post form data from ExtJS and return a custom class ApiResponse {success(bool), msg(string), ds(DataSet) } which is converted nicely into JSON.
**Can I call this from Windows Phone 8 HttpClient?** The built in version doesn't seem to allow me to use NamedValueCollection.

Comment: If I change my backend to:
"public ApiResponse Process(string id, dynamic form)..."
and serialize Dictionary<string, object> it works.
If I change to:
public ApiResponse Process(string id, string form)...
it is not found. Not sure why sending a serialized string would connect with "dynamic form" but not "string form"
Also, I could not just send a json string to dynamic form it had to be serialized from Dictionary<string, object> or it would be NotFound.
I don't like the Dictionary to json serialization as it produces extra key/value words in the json string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about your quesiton If I got it right you're asking if you can invoke a JSON endpoint from WP8. Yes, you can. Take the resulting JSON over to http://json2chsarp.com and it'll generate JSON.net classes for you. Then use JSON.Net's JsonDeserializer to deserialize the JSON text back to objects.

Comment: Thanks your response.Web Essentials adds ability to paste JSON as a class right within Visual Studio.
I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way to code client and WebAPI for passing a collection of values to the server and returning JSON and have it populate an, if possible, generic or should I say dynamic class.
With Phone 8 the HttpClient does allow the NamedValueCollection so it looks like I have to use a dictionary<string, object>ToJson string,but then it looks like the webApi cannot receive FormDataCollection but must be a string or class.
I get service not found though IE can see it.